# Kinect SDK facial expression data

Tags: kinect, avatar

Is it possible to get facial expression data from the Avatar feature of the Kinect SDK? I need to get the strength of certain emotions in the face that is being filmed for example 30% happy 20 % surprised etc. Is it possible to make this happen?

If yes: How?

If not: What other options do I have, besides very expensive software?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, [Kinect for Windows SDK 1.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/developer-downloads.aspx) supports face tracking and makes it possible to fit a 3D mesh to users’ faces and track their facial features and head position in real time using components from the Developer Toolkit. The Kinect Developer Tookit supplies two examples demonstrating how to extract users face information. For more information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131043

Answer (score 0):

I believe I read somewhere this is in the pipeline to be added into the sdk, but is not in the current version. There may be a open source alternative somewhere that will let you bolt on the functionality but chances are it is designed for OpenNI and not the official SDK.